# Передать меню с wordpress в установленный в папке Opencart

Tags: wordpress, opencart

Суть вопроса в том, что в корне на домене стоит информационный сайт на Wordpress, а в папке /shop/ установлен Opencart. Существует ли метод у вордпреса для передачи меню в виде массива ил json в опенкарт?
Может бред, но вдруг кто-то знает метод простой.
Подключить базу и получать mysql запросами могу, может есть другой способ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно расширить существующий REST Wordpress

Прописать в functions.php темы следующий код

```
function get_menu() {
    return wp_get_nav_menu_items('menu');
}

add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
        register_rest_route( 'mymenu', '/menu', array(
        'methods' => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'get_menu',
    ) );
} );
```

Меню будет доступно по адресу http://your-domain.dev/wp-json/wp/v2/mymenu/menu

В wp_get_nav_menu_items('menu') указать slug своего меню

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете использовать rest api для получения меню, для этого вам нужно зарегистрировать конечную точку используя экшн `rest_api_init` и функцию `register_rest_route` в которой вы можете указать второй параметр динамически чтоб не хардить конкретное меню

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'register_rest_route_for_menu' );

function register_rest_route_for_menu() {
    register_rest_route( 'wp/v2, '/menu/(?P<slug>[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)', 
        [
            'methods' => 'GET',
            'callback' => 'get_menu_by_slug',
        ]
   );
}

function get_menu_by_slug( WP_REST_Request $request ) {
    $menu = wp_get_nav_menu_items( $request[ 'slug' ] );

    return $menu ? $menu : new WP_Error( 'menu_not_found', 'menu not found', [ 'status' => 404 ] );
}
```

После чего вы можете обращаться через эту конечную точку к api

`/wp-json/wp/v2/menu/{slug}`

где `slug` может быть ID, ярлык или название меню